# How is X-server configured with Windows XP?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, imagemagick, xserve

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ImageMagick import command gives error on windows??](https://superuser.com/questions/179284/imagemagick-import-command-gives-error-on-windows)

Well I have installed two X-Servers that are Xming And Cygwin.

As the import command of ImageMagick works on linux/unix based OS but on Windows it requires X-Server.
So how can I configure any of the X-Servers so that ImageMagick import command will save screen images for me on Windows OS?

Any help and links will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Does this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/179284/imagemagick-import-command-gives-error-on-windows/182747#182747 help?