# ImageMagick import command gives error on windows?

Tags: windows-xp, imagemagick, xserve

I get the following error when I run the `import` command of ImageMagick from command-line

```
import: unable to open X sever '(null)'  @error /import.c/ImportImageCommand/362 [No such file or directory]
```

However, I have installed X-Server and it is launched in my task-bar. Even then I get this error.

Could you please provide me with some relevant links or solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If the Windows magick works like the *nix one, then you can try setting DISPLAY environment variable prior to calling it, e.g.

```
set DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
import ...
```

Comment: Try the localhost:0.0 instead

Comment: but what that means , i tried 

localhost

it gives me this error

'localhost' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: i am not using php and i just want to capture image from command-line through imagicmagick??

Comment: I thought that ImageMagick doesn't have an address of X server to connect to, and that is reason of this error, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: @Muhammad Irfan: The error means that the DISPLAY variable is not set.  If you get "localhost' is not recognized as a command", then you made a mistake setting it. Try `set DISPLAY=:0` or `set DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0`; many Windows installations don't know "localhost".

Comment: @Aaron, that's interesting. Isn't it aliased in `hosts` by default?

Comment: @whitequark: It *should* be in hosts but it's not by default.

Comment: And the hosts file is located in windows/system32/driver/etc/hosts
i checked that file and when i install Flashcs5 and FlashBuilder4, i changed host file data.. 
i am at imageMagick directory and 
set DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0;
it works, gives no error
but import.. gives SAME ERROR again.

Answer (score 0):

Windows by default doesn't include an "X Server". You need to install one that is made for Windows first. And it must run when you start ImageMagick's `display` or `import` commands.

I would recommend to install the public domain version of the [XMing package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/) ([documentation](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/changes.php)). Then, simply launch 
`xlaunch.exe` and confirm all default settings. This will get the X Server running on localhost:0.0. Once it runs, your ImageMagick commands `import` and `display` will work, at least if you call them like this:

```
 import -server localhost:0.0 ....
 display -server localhost:0.0 ....
```